# Express A^(-1) matrix as linear combination of A^2, A and I3

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, matrix-equations

I am a bit confused. How can I express A^(-1) matrix as linear combination of A^2,  A and I3?

This is the matrix A: [0, 0, 7], [1, 0, 3], [0, 1, 8]

I found A^2 to be [0, 7, 56], [0, 3, 31], [1, 8, 67]

Thanks

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Your question is phrased as an isolated problem, without any further information or context. This does not match [many users' quality standards](http://goo.gl/mLWc8), so it may attract downvotes, or closed. To prevent that, please [edit] the question. [This](http://goo.gl/PlJyVQ) will help you recognise and resolve the issues. Concretely: please provide context, and include your work and thoughts on the problem. These changes can help in formulating more appropriate answers.

Comment: The characteristic equation of the matrix might help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$$
       A-\lambda I=\left[\begin{array}{ccc}-\lambda & 0 & 7 \\ 1 & \lambda & 3 \\ 0 & 1 & 8-\lambda
               \end{array}\right]
$$
The characteristic polynomial is
\begin{align}
       \mbox{det}(A-\lambda I)&=-\lambda^2(8-\lambda)+7-(-3\lambda)\\
 &=\lambda^3-8\lambda^2+3\lambda+7
\end{align}
Therefore
$$
                A^3-8A^2+3A=-7I \\
                A(A^2-8A+3I)=-7I \\
                A^{-1}=-\frac{1}{7}(A^2-8A+3I).
$$

Comment: Hey, I hope I'm not breaking any guidelines asking you this, but is there a way to reach you personally?

Comment: @iamsoboredofmathhh : Is there something in particular you wanted to know?